# Recommended Software Design Pattern to define CSV/XML or any other format generator?

Tags: php, xml, oop, csv, design-patterns

Hi I'm writing a CSV/XML package for my own project, I'm not using packages around there because I need to render for some cases CSVs with more than 100.000.000 of rows. So I figured my basic solution doesn't work when the database queries take long time, then I wrote a script to download the file batching it. It's working I just want extend and re-factor it for XML. Would be great do it with a good design pattern.

Comment: No pattern meets *any other format generator*. You must make visible what specific problem you'd like to solve so that a useful suggestion on patterns can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several libraries working on this kind of subject in PHP are implementing a [design pattern adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) because standard PHP libraries (that you should use if you want performances) associated to each kind of file provide a completely different interface.

So, in fact, you just have to find your own interface (you can do that with many interfaces if you can identify different functional aspects).

> Example of standard library for CSV in PHP: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php
>
> Example of abstraction tool on type of file: https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette

Answer (score 1):

This question is primarily opinion-based - I will tell how I have solved this problem.
I have recently met the same problem in one of my projects and I decided to solve this problem with writing reading and writing interfaces.
As result, I had a code like:

```
public interface IReportReader
{
    Report ReadFromFile(string filePath);
    Report ReadFromStream(Stream stream);
}

public interface IReportWriter
{
    void WriteToFile(string filePath, Report report);
    void WriteToStream(Stream stream, Report report); 
}
```

Then, I have implemented two implementations:

`StubConsoleReportReader` \ `StubConsoleReportWriter` - just for debug purposes.
`CSVReportReader` \ `CSVReportWriter`.

Later, I have easily added XML, HTML and word output formats.

As for me, this pattern suits great because:
1. It is plain and simple, without over-engineering, can be easily extended;
2. These two interfaces describe two fundamental operations - input and output, which are fitting any existing file types and formats.

Comment: I'm agree with you, is a opinion-based question. Just looking for a good conceptualization to make my code maintainable and easy to extend.

Comment: For easy extension, the first interface is useless as an interface. The method in that case could be just `getReport` and should return the **Report** object. Similar for the writer, it should just write so that it can be exchanged more easily. Right now the interfaces suggested here just contain all the details (streams and strings) that you normally want to defer. Also which pattern this answer should represent still is a secret of the user answering here, all shared is that it's a pattern (*"this pattern suits"*). I don't think it's a pttern at all, it just promotes to use interfaces.